# How to find mean/median/mode based on distinctive groups in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am extremely new to R and programming, so I don't even know how to describe my question very clearly, excuse me for using an example to further explain what I mean:

Say I have a data frame with 2 columns, first one being 10 different countries, second column is the rate of happiness (0-10). And country column could have lots of repeated ones, e.g.:

Column titles: Country  Happiness
1st Column content: A,C,A,B,B,B,C,A,D,D....
2nd Column content: 10,9,3,4,4,5,6,9,10,6...

What I want to achieve is: get mean/median/mode for country A B C D respectively. So far using describe() function I can only get the MMM for all the numbers, rather than by country.

I wonder if there is a function to achieve this directly, or should I create subsets of each country first? How should I do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Have you looked at `dplyr::group_by` and `summarise` workflow? there are loads of resources for this on-line for example https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this best with `dplyr` but first you will have to write a function for the mode:

```
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v[!is.na(v)])
  uniqv[which.max(table(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

Now you can `group_by`the grouping variable `Country` and use `summarise` to calculate the statistics:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Happiness),
            Median = median(Happiness),
            Mode = getmode(Happiness))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Country  Mean Median  Mode
* <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1 A         2.5    2.5     2
2 B         2      2       2
3 C         3      3       3
4 D         3.5    3.5     5
```

Data:

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  Country = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace = T),
  Happiness = sample(1:5, 10, replace = T)
)
```

Comment: You can use the modeest package instead of creating your own: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeest/modeest.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for your thanks. Pls consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped you.